# css3 in facebook app

Tags: css, facebook

this doesn't work in a facebook application?

```
q:before { content: '\00AB';   color: #FF0000; }
q:after { content: '\00BB';  color: #FF0000; }
```

Comment: CSS3 only works [properly] in supported browsers. What browser are you testing with?

Comment: Does Facebook parse CSS before it's ran to make sure it can't cover their ads? I know it sounds silly, but back in the Myspace days, they'd actually purge some CSS that could hide ads.

Comment: @atomiton, opera 10.50 and firefox 3.6.3. the code works quite fine if testing normally, but not in a facebook application.

Comment: Does it work with non-hex content?

Comment: @syntax error, i'm new to all this. can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building an FBML application, then yes, your CSS will be filtered through Facebook's content rendering servers.  They do this with all FBML pages and referenced resources in order to prefix all your HTML/CSS/JS elements with a "namespace" created using your application id.  This ensures that your CSS can't mess with the primary Facebook layouts.

Unfortunately, their CSS filters seem to disallow some CSS.  For example, I have found that all the Firefox specific CSS rules such as `-moz-border-radius: 3px` work fine, but the corresponding `-webkit-border-radius: 3px` [does not work](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=150186).  Very annoying.

My suggestion is to find the rewritten CSS file and see what they've done with it.  You'll have to *view source* on your FBML page and look for the CSS files, they generally come from `http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/fbml_static_get.php`, with a query string that will look like the actual source.  Check out your CSS file and you'll see how it's been re-written... I believe I've used the `content:` rule before, so perhaps it's being sanitized in some way.

Answer (score 0):

If it's showing question marks instead of the quotes then that usually means you have an encoding issue. The hex-content I mentioned is the '\00AB' part. That's the hex equivalent of an angled quotation mark, otherwise known as &laquo; or &#171; ...it shows a «

Try this:

```
q:before { content: 'test';   color: #FF0000; }
```

To verify that normal text content is working ok - it should insert the word "test".

I played with this a little and I seemed to have trouble with the font I was using, when I switched to arial it suddenly started working, so you could try that. If it works you don't need to change the font for everything, just q:before and q:after

Comment: The test content, or the font change? Or neither?